# add if no duplicate in collection mongodb python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, upsert

i'm writing a script that puts a large number of xml files into mongodb, thus when i execute the script multiple times the same object is added many times to the same collection.

I checked out for a way to stop this behavior by checkinng the existance of the object before adding it, but can't find a way.

help!

Answer (score 1):

The term for the operation you're describing is ["upsert"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsert).

In mongodb, the way to upsert is to use the [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) functionality with `upsert=True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can index on one or more fields(not _id) of the document/xml structure. Then make use of `find` operator to check if a document containing that indexed_field:value is present in the collection. If it returns nothing then you can insert new documents into your collection. This will ensure only new docs are inserted when you re-run the script.

Comment: actualy i found out something like db.collection.find(object).limit(1) returns the first object it finds matching "object", i can't use $exist like that : db.collection.find(o, {$exist:true}), can i?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion caused, "$exists" does not make sens in this scenario. Just use "find" but on an indexed field so that the query is faster.